# Xcode can not get source files from SVN repo

Tags: svn, xcode

HI,

I have set up a SVN repository in an external machine via command line and using mac os x and works great.

Now I want Xcode (snow leopard) to get the source fron the repo, but I get a lots of errors, and have no clue what is going on.

Could you point me to some godo tutorial or link for this? I googled but found nothing good.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about the actual errors ?

Comment: I can check out the files from the repo, into xcode, but can not associate to the project, i.e., can not work with them !

Comment: You need to set the repository for the project in the Project Settings window's General tab.

Comment: yes, I did it

.can you tell me which totorial or guide did you follow?

Answer (score 0):

Under the SCM menu, select repositories. Then add a new repository, paste in the URL section the exact same URL you would use on the command line, e.g.: svn+ssh://polymicrosystems.com/home/tgunr/svn/pms

The rest of the lines should auto fill. Put in your name and password and it should connect to your SVN host.

[Example pix here](http://mp.polymicro.net/temp/images/Screen%20shot%202010-02-28%20at%209.27.37%20AM.png)